# Using GIN and mvp4g

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin, gwt-dispatch, gwt-mvp

I'd like to use gwt-dispatch Command Patter implementation in my app. I'm using also mvp4g. How can I make `DefaultDispatchAsync` available to inject *into* my presenters using GIN or make it globally available, so I can access it *from* my presenters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a bind for the DefaultDispatchAsync class in your gin module. This will setup the binding for the DispatchAsync interface that the DefaultDispatchAsync class implements. You can then add a DispatchAsync to your presenter constructor and have it injected by gin as required.

I normally then have my presenters contain a private DispatchAsync member, which i assign the injected DispatchAsync argument to inside the constructor. Then the dispatch can be used in the presenter class as required.

So in your GinModule's configure method, add the line

```
bind(DefaultDispatchAsync.class);
```

Then on your presenter constructor,

```
@Inject
public TestPresenter(/*Other injected arguments*/, final DispatchAsync dispatcher) {
   this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
}
```

Comment: I have to setup my injector and ginmodule during application startup, so I assume it will be somewhere in my gwt module entry point?

Comment: Yes, you can use GWT create to setup your Ginjector in your Entrypoint class. 

e.g. private final GwtGinjector injector = GWT.create(GwtGinjector.class);

You can then use the instance of the injector created to retrieve your top level presenter and kick off your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it basically works, but now I need some help with the gwt-dispatch questions, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776726/connecting-gwt-dispatch-with-guice-and-mvp4g